# Get simple string array from Angular 11 observables

Tags: arrays, angular, observable

I am trying to get simple string array from my GET call in Angular. I need this array for matching purpose inside the code. I dont need to expose it to DOM by *ngFor.

Currently I am getting

```
[]
0: (4) ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
```

with this code:

```
projects: string[] = [];

this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}`)
      .pipe(
        map((data: any) => data.response.body
          .map(item => {
              return item.shortName;
            }
          )
        )
      ).subscribe((project: any) => {

      this.projects.push(project);
    });
```

The problem is that getting first element of list:

this.projects[0] = undefined

Manual pushing of string array

const proje = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
by

```
this.projects.push(proje);
```

returns:

```
[Array(4)]
0: (4) ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
```

that would be absolutely fine and
this.projects[0] = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'].

Any idea would be appreciated. thanks

Comment: Where in your code are you trying this.projects[0] = undefined? This is probably just an async thing..

Answer (score 0):

This is an async call. JavaScript does not wait for it to finish and proceeds with the next lines of code. If you `console.log()` directly after this call, you'll always see an undefined array, as it gets filled much later.

```
this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}`)
  .pipe(
    map((data: any) => data.response.body
      .map(item => {
          return item.shortName;
        }
      )
    )
  ).subscribe((project: any) => {

  this.projects.push(project);

  // have a look here
  console.log(this.projects);
});
```

Comment: Right, but it is not enough for me. I need to put that array into variable in order to be used in custom input field validator to prevent duplicate entry.

Comment: Did you try an async validator?

Comment: No, will look at this if it fits my needs.

Comment: As I understood async validator, it calls some api on every change of user input field  resp.select query from db fetching  entered value. It returns boolean that is valuated on dedicated field for matching. It seems that might have a quite big impact on app performance. Am I right? I would prefer to call api only once on component initialization and validate input change against this retrieved list.

Comment: I implemented async validator, that works fine excecpt one thing. It does not display error message because error is as list:{0: {…}}
0: {duplicateShortName: true}. Sync Validators looks directly like {minlength: {…}}
minlength:
actualLength: 1
requiredLength: 3